# Custom Popup window while unpublishing an item in SDL Tridion 2011

Tags: 2011

In SDL Tridion 2011 is there any possibility, while Unpublishing an item,
to rather than showing the regular popup window `Publish.aspx`, showing a custom popup window?

This is required for items inside one Publication only, when unpublishing those items. We want to show a custom popup first and then show the regular publish popup.

Comment: May i know, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Please don't use the comments for thanking somebody for an answer, you can do that by voting on the answer. Use comments only to ask for more information or suggest improvents. I've edited your question and added your additional information in there (you can do that yourself too). Could you provide information on what that custom popup is exactly needed for, what things will be shown or set in there for example? This information can be useful to provide you with a valid answer.

Answer (score 6):

I'd be really interested to know what the use case is here and what you're trying to do, i've some code to also inject additional script and buttosn into the publish dialog, but it's in a very buggy state, would be happy to share :)

It's a lot easier to add your own functionality (an icon in the context menu, ribbon) rather than overriding the UpPublish, after all there may be a need to keep existing un-publish behaviour.

Comment: Here is the Usecase.

Comment: Usecase : Users are trying to Unpublish the Items from Marketing Publicaion. But due to some issues it is not unpublishing because of this all other Publishing\Unpublishing activities are getting delayed. So we want show the popup with a message contact Administrators to unpublish the Items in Marketing publication. So it didn't impact other Users Activites.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to do by overriding the regular UnPublish command.

- You will need to define and develop your own popup registering it as a brand new view.
- You will need to develop a new command that will extend the existing UnPublish command.
- Your brand new UnPublish command will call your brand new view.

Why do you want to stop using the Publish.aspx popup?

You can show your custom popup and then show the Publish popup as well.

Comment: Possible indeed but might I add not recommended since this disturbs the normal flow and might confuse the customer more than it can help them.